# not a TeX source file: cannot compile

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

I'm working now on Sublime Text 3 as text editor for LaTeX, and I'm using LaTeXTools. So far so good. However, I've just created a new file [Ctr+N], I've checked that the syntax is written in LaTeX View/Syntax/LaTeX/LaTeX. I've also checked the builder system Tools/Build System /Latex.
However, when try to compile Ctr+B it says "is not a TeX source file: cannot compile".

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Hello, welcome to TeX.sx! `:)` An empty file is _not a valid_ LaTeX file. You need to have at least a basic document structure: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: Does your file have `.tex` extension?

Comment: Yes, it has a structure.\documentclass{paper}

\documentclass[10pt,letter]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
 

\begin{document}

\end{document}

Comment: Yes, I saved the file Save as LaTeX *.tex  I see the file but it does not appear with the extension. I've tried several times.  Should I just do it manually in the folder? (It seems not proper though)

Comment: Also, when checking the system, everything seems correct but the following Builder Setting  Value
---------------  -----
display_log      False
linux            {}   
osx              {}   
windows          {}   

TeX Root